# oracle help missing comma

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating this table in oracle

```
CREATE TABLE COURSE  (
     COURSE NUMBER(8,0) PRIMARY KEY,
     DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR2(50) NULL,
     COST NUMBER(9,2) NULL,
     PEREQUISITE NUMBER(8,0)  NULL,
     CREATED_BY VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
     CREATED_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
     MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
     MODIFIED_DATE DATE NOT NULL
);
```

on doing the following insert I keep getting missing comma error but no comma is missing

```
INSERT INTO COURSE 
  ( COURSE NUMBER,DESCRIPTION,COST,PEREQUISITE NUMBER,CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE)
VALUES 
  (4823001,'Info Security Administration',1500,3153,'Moussa Kone','01/28/10','Moussa Kone','01/28/10');
```

Answer (score 12):

```
INSERT INTO COURSE ( COURSE NUMBER, ...
                 ... PEREQUISITE NUMBER, ...
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO COURSE ( COURSE, ...
                 ... PEREQUISITE, ...
```

PS: Shouldn't `PEREQUISITE` be spelled `PREREQUISITE`?

Comment: +1: Good catch on the data type getting included in the list of columns.

Answer (score 5):

Strip all those `NUMBER` you have in your `INSERT` statement. They're not part of the column name, they're the column type; and Oracle doesn't know why they're in the `INSERT` statement.

You have them twice: after your `COURSE` column, and after your `PREREQUISITE` column.

```
INSERT INTO COURSE (COURSE, DESCRIPTION, COST, PEREQUISITE, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_DATE)
   VALUES (4823001,'Info Security Administration',1500,3153,'Moussa Kone','01/28/10','Moussa Kone','01/28/10');
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably just a copy paste error, but I think Oracle insist a comma between 'course' and 'number'. So, I'd say that the solution is to remove 'number' and thus the correct insert statement is as follows

```
INSERT INTO COURSE ( COURSE ,DESCRIPTION,COST,PEREQUISITE,CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE)
   VALUES (4823001,'Info Security Administration',1500,3153,'Moussa Kone','01/28/10','Moussa Kone','01/28/10');
```