# missing comma error in oracle query

Tags: oracle10g

I am getting error while inserting a row in database.

Error: ORA-00917: missing comma

But there is no comma missing in my query.
Below is the query:

INSERT INTO Customer (NEED_BY_DATE) VALUES('|| 'to_date('|| ''''|| v_in_need_by_date|| ''''|| ','|| ''''|| 'MM-DD-YYYY'|| ''''|| ')'|| ');

Comment: Check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164517/oracle-help-missing-comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes and pipes before to_date: `... VALUES('|| 'to_date...` shouldn't be there, `||` is used to concatenate strings and ' is not a string. Same thing goes on further. 
I believe that you want something like:
`INSERT INTO Customer (NEED_BY_DATE) VALUES(to_date(v_in_need_by_date));`